Difference between sound volume in wpctl and pw-dump
I am a total Linux beginner (I installed Fedora Workstation 40 a week ago) and I want to learn how to control sound volume and input/output from the terminal in a similar way that the GUI handles it. I can use amixer or alsamixer but these tools are limited.
The best option would be wpctl but I don't understand why the volume shown with pw-dump is different. I think it should be a lower-level volume, but can someone please explain how this works? Thanks in advance
